# changing language in .NET MAUI Blazor with ASP.NET MVC API

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, blazor, maui, maui-blazor

I have 2 applications:

- .Net Maui Blazor mobile app
- ASP.NET MVC API to do some server stuff.

and now I have a couple of methods in LanguageController, one of them is ChangeLanguageApi()

```
  [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult ChangeLanguageApi([FromBody]string culture)
        {
            if (culture == null || !_supportedLanguages.Contains(culture))
            {
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound,
                    new Response { IsSuccess = false, Message = Common.SomethingWentWrong,  });
            }
            Response.Cookies.Append(CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
                CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(culture)),
                new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMonths(6) });

            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status200OK,
                    new Response { IsSuccess = true, Message = Common.Success,  });
        }
```

Program.cs looks like this:

```
builder.Services.Configure<LanguageSettings>(options => builder.Configuration.GetSection("LanguageSettings").Bind(options));
builder.Services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
var mvcBuilder = builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(options =>
{
    var type = typeof(Resources.Common);
    var assembly = new AssemblyName(type.GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName);
    var factory = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IStringLocalizerFactory>();
    var localizer = factory.Create("Common", assembly.Name);
    options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (t, f) => localizer;
});
var app = builder.Build();
var languageSettings = builder.Configuration.GetSection("LanguageSettings:SupportedLanguages").Get<List<string>>();
var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>();
languageSettings.ForEach(x => supportedCultures.Add(new CultureInfo(x)));
app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en"),
    SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
    SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
});
```

this 2 parts of code are from API

Below code in Blazor App responsible for changing language (returnResponse.Message is always in same langugage)

```
        public async Task<Response> ChangeLanguage(string language)
        {
            var returnResponse = new Response();
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var url = $"{Settings.BaseUrl}{Apis.ChangeLanguage}";

                var serializedStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(language);

                var response = await client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(serializedStr, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string contentStr = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    returnResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(contentStr);
                }
            }
            return returnResponse;
        }
```

So basically I store some available cultures in appsettings.json and every resource is keeped in .resx files like on the screen
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEIPs.png)

And now, when I use Swagger/Postman to test my API, I get translated message in response object according to culture that I post, but in my Blazor mobile app it does not change. It looks like this cookie does not work for my Blazor app.
coockie for changing to polish language:
[image: Swagger proper coockie for pl language change]
coockie for changing to english language:
[image: Swagger proper coockie for english language change]
No coockie in blazor when it is used same endpoint:
[image: No coockie in Blazor using same API endpoint]
Android Emulator and Windows app build work in the same way. I would like to display messages according to posted `string culture`
Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

Use [bit TodoTemplate](https://bitplatform.dev/todo-template/multilingualism)! it has Multilingual sample and has a lot of more features.